# R plot using ggplot facet_grid add legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Using `ggplot` and `faced_grid`, I have a problem to visualize the entire name of type1 variable. The name is too long. How I can add a legend for avoid this problem?

```
DF <- data.frame("value" =  runif(50, 0, 1),
                 "type1" = c(rep("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", 25), 
                             rep("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", 25)),
                 "type2" = rep(c("c", "d"), 25), 
                 "number" = rep(2:6, 10))

ggplot(DF, aes(y = value, x = type1)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha = .3) + 
  ggtitle("TITLE") + 
  facet_grid(type2 ~ number)
```

This is the results:

[image: CODE RESULT]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option where we fill by `type1`.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(y=value, x=type1)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=.3, aes(fill = type1)) + 
  ggtitle("TITLE") + facet_grid(type2 ~ number) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL, breaks = NULL) + # these lines are optional
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]